# Get image size in bytes to check for bad images

Tags: php

How do I get image size in bytes. This is for detecting bad image urls.

Example: I have two image links in my database

1. im1.jpg
2. im2.jpg

but, only `im1.jpg` is available in "img" folder.

I want to detect the bad image URLs, so I can remove them.

If there is any other way, please help.

Comment: So, do you want to get the image size in bytes, or check whether or not the file exists on the local file system?

Answer (score 3):

Use [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check if file exists and use [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) to check file size ;)